# Не работает <picture> <source>

Tags: адаптивная-верстка

Прошу прощения за нубский вопрос.

Есть такой код:

```html
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 769px)" type="image/png" srcset="assets/img/bi.png">
    <source media="(max-width: 768px)" type="image/png" srcset="assets/img/bi_mobile.png">
    <!-- <img src="assets/img/bi.png" alt=""> -->
</picture>
```

Но он почему-то не работает. Если использовать просто тэг img, картинка отображается, но мне нужно менять изображение.

Всем спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: Посмотрел, все должно работать, только img верните. Картинка bi.png будет обображаться при ширине менее 769 пикселей, а bi_mobile должна появляться при ширини минимум 769

Comment: Swad, спасибо! я думал, img нужен только если не подходит ни один из source